# Django: после успешного login() при следующего обновления страницы request.user снова становится anonymous

Tags: python, django

Всем добрый день!
Я сделала кастомный метод авторизации, а именно
У меня авторизация происходит с помощью ajax

Вот, собственно, сама вьюха

```
class CustomLogin(LoginView):
    authentication_form = CustomUserAuthForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            needed_user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

            if needed_user is not None:
                if needed_user.is_active:
                    login(request, needed_user)

                    request.session['night_mode'] = False
                    request.session.save()
                    return JsonResponse({'success': 1})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'errors': 'Email and password didn\'t match.'})

        if form.errors:
            errors = []
            for key, value in enumerate(form.errors):
                errors += form.errors[value]

            return JsonResponse({'errors': errors})

        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Форма:

```
<!-- Modal AUTHORIZATION -->
<div id="auth_view" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close close_model" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <i class="fal fa-times" style="font-size: 16px;"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="modal-body__title">
                    Authorization
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body__form-container">
                    <div class="form-container">
                        <form id="auth_view__form" class="form-container__form" method="post"
                              enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <p id="error-message"></p>

                            {% for field in auth_form %}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                                    {{ field }}
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <input type="submit" value="login">
                            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
                            <p id="password_reset"><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot password</a></p>
                            <div class="or_container">
                                <hr>
                                <div class="or_label">or</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="auth_by_socials">
                                <div class="auth_by_facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></div>
                                <div class="auth_by_google"><i class="fab fa-google"></i></div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="registration">
                                <div>Sign up with e-mail</div>
                                <i class="fal fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ajax:

```
    $('#auth_view__form').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'login_modal' %}",
            data: $('#auth_view__form').serialize(),
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data['errors']) {
                    $('#error-message').html(data['errors']);
                } else if (data['success']) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

backends.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class CustomAuthBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        usr = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = usr.objects.get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except usr.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return None
        except usr.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        usr = get_user_model()
        try:
            return usr.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except usr.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

и всё хорошо, но при обновлении страницы юзер разлогинивается

и всё раньше работало, но после того, как я подняла сервер на удаленной машине, она стала вести себя таким вот образом. Есть какие-то идеи? Заранее спасибо!

P.S.: то есть на `return JsonResponse({'success': 1})` request.user равен пользователю, который авторизовался

Answer (score 0):

Всё стало работать, когда я сделала в `settings.py` следующее:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```